# Product of weak and strong convergent sequences in $L^p$

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I already saw some proofs here with $b_n\to b$ in $L^2$ and $a_n\rightharpoonup a$ in $L^2$. Then
$$
\int a_n b_n \to \int a b.
$$

But what goes wrong if both sequences are weak convergent?

Proof:

$$
\int_\Omega a_nb_n\,dx \to \int_\Omega ab\,dx.
$$ 
Indeed,
$$
a_nb_n-ab=a_n(b_n-b)+(a_n-a)b
$$
Then
$$
\Big|\int_\Omega a_n(b_n-b)\,dx\,\Big|\le 
\|a_n\|_{L^2}\|b_n-b\|_{L^2}\le M\|b_n-b\|_{L^2}\to 0,
$$
and
$$
\int_\Omega (a_n-a)b \to 0, 
$$
as $a_n-a\rightharpoonup 0$.

Why does not hold
$$ \int_\Omega a_n(b_n-b)\,dx\,\to 0,$$
if $b_n\rightharpoonup b$.

Answer (score 4):

Then it may fail. Let $a_n(x)=b_n(x)=\sin(n\,x)$. By the Riemamm-Lebesgue lemma, $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge weakly to $0$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, but
$$
 a_n\,b_n=\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2\,n\,x)}{2}
$$
converges wekly to $1/2$.

Comment: ok thx but what goes wrong in the proof?

Comment: I do not see any proof in your question.

Comment: @user1952009 $L^2([-\pi,\pi])\subset L^1([-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: yes I saw that, I needed some time :) can you find such a counter-example in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ too ?

Comment: @user1952009 Let $a_n=b_n$ be the characteristic function of $[-\pi,\pi]$ times $\sin(n\,x)$.

Comment: I guess any orthonormal family of $L^2$ will do the trick : $a_n = b_n = e_n$ are weakly convergent to $0$

Comment: I added a proof

Comment: What goes wrong is that $b_n\rightharpoonup b$ does not imply that $\|b_n-b\|_{L^2}\to0$ (used in the third displayed formula.)

Comment: I added one line

Comment: It just does not hold in general. Why? Because weak convergence is not strong enough.